# Why is the charging animation is not working

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page title</title>
    <style>
        div{
            background: green;
            width: 700px;
            height: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .dot{
            background: #55eaff9d;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            border-radius: 30px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            margin: 10px 10px;
        }

        .blink{
            background: lightgreen;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
<script>
    let container = document.querySelector("div");
    let dots = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        let dot = document.createElement("canvas");
        dot.classList.add("dot");
        let currentID = "dot" + i;
        dot.id = currentID;
        dots.push(currentID);
        container.append(dot);
    }

    console.log(dots)

    function changeColorRandom(index) {
        id = "dot" + (index + 1);
        let element = document.getElementById(id);
        element.classList.add("blink");
    }

    function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    async function powerAll(ids) {
        for(id of ids) {
            element = document.getElementById(id);
            element.classList.add("blink")
            await sleep(500);
        }
    }

    function clearAll(ids) {
        for(id of ids) {
            element = document.getElementById(id);
            element.classList.remove("blink");
        }
    }
    setInterval(async function() {
        await powerAll(dots);
        clearAll(dots);
    }, 1000);
</script>
</html>
```

Can somebody please try to run this code and see why it does not work as it should? It should look like charging animation repeatedly.

I tried everything, but nothing helped me. Please somebody help me in this code. I know I am misunderstanding something here.

Answer (score 0):

Before the powerAll() finishes you're firing more intervals:

```
setInterval(async function() {
    await powerAll(dots);
    clearAll(dots);
}, 1000);
```

try changing this to:

```
setInterval(async function() {
    await powerAll(dots);
    clearAll(dots);
}, 3500);
```

The only issue is now it will start with a 3.5s delay,
so make it into a function and fire it right away, etc.
powerAll() takes 3s to finish so you have to give it time.

Something like this maybe:
https://jsfiddle.net/j7ofbgw1/